# Problema al interactuar con dict Python

Tags: python

Tengo mi siguiente código:

```
for noms in json_obj['nom']:
    Type = noms.split("-")
    x = Type[1]
    y = Type[2]
```

En donde `json_obj['nom']` tiene los siguientes valores:

```
[{u'nom': u'7558-802'}, {u'nom': u'7558-998'}]
```

Lo que busco es que en "x" se guarde el valor 7558 y en "y" se guarde 802 y 998

Pero cuando corro mi programa me manda el sig error:

```
Type = noms.split("-")
AttributteError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien lo que quieres, en `json_obj['nom']` tienes una lista de diccionarios de los que sólo te interesa los valores de la clave `nom`. Esto valores son *"tuplas"* que quieres agrupar por el primer elemento de la tupla.

O sea, de:

```
[{u'nom': u'7558-802'}, {u'nom': u'7558-998'}]
```

quieres pasar a

```
(x,y) = ('7558',['802','998'])
```

Lo primero es sacar la lista de tuplas:

```
tuplas = [s["nom"].split("-") for s in json_obj['nom']]

# tuplas --> [['7558', '802'], ['7558', '998']]
```

Para agrupar por el primer elemento de las tuplas habría varias formas de hacerlo, pero una sencilla:

```
d = {}
for k,v in tuplas:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

# d -> {'7558': ['802','998']}
```

Ya casi está. Lo último que queda es iterar entre los *items* del diccionario:

```
for x,y in d.items():
    print(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ocurre que `json_obj['nom']` **es una lista** que contiene dos diccionarios.

Si dices que json_obj['nom'] tiene `[{u'nom': u'7558-802'}, {u'nom': u'7558-998'}]` puedo hacer:

```
lista = [{u'nom': u'7558-802'}, {u'nom': u'7558-998'}]
```

y al ver su tipo, se aclara el asunto:

```
>>> type(lista)
```

Si podrías hacer algo como esto para obtener el elemento requerido y poder dividirlo.

```
>>> for noms in lista:
...     Type = noms['nom'].split('-')
...     x = Type[0]
...     y = Type[1]
...
```

> El algoritmo que planteas almacena en `x` y en `y` solo el último ciclo `for`, por lo que solo contiene `x = 7558` y `y = 998`. Existen varias alternativas para lo que quieres, pero debes abrir una nueva pregunta, ya que el tema es diferente del actual.